# How can i draw a set of lines and areas in Objective-C?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, opengl-es

I need to make a program for iPad. This program has to manage a planimetry.

In your opinion, what's the best way to draw a planimetry (made in xml by a set of tag `line` with `x` and `y` coordinates) by assuring a good performance?

You have to consider that each planimetry is composed by thousand lines. Since pinching and translating can ruin performance (maybe), do you think that the best way to do that is to use a particular render (2d/3d)?

Can OpenGL help me? I wish manipulation of planimetry (traslation, rotation, zoom) is fluid. No jumps.

Comment: You'll get a better reception here, and better help as well, if you read [the relevant documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007853) before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz / CoreGraphics seems to be the best solution for 2D. I think it's HW accelerated.

[Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066)